# can not load private key using ssh-add

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, ssh-keys

I tried to create a ssh key by doing following command:

```
ssh-keygen -t dsa
```

then it prompts me to enter store path:

```
Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/KesongXie/.ssh/id_dsa): id_dsa
```

after I entering my passphrase, i got the following result

```
Your identification has been saved in id_dsa.
Your public key has been saved in id_dsa.pub.
```

Then i tried to load my private ssh key using the followibg command

```
ssh-add /Users/KesongXie/.ssh/id_dsa
```

It shows the result:

```
-bash: ssh-add/Users/KesongXie/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
```

When I navigate to my local diretory, Users/KesongXie, and I can not find the .ssh file(as expected , doc files are hidden ), but when I tried to view it in my terminal, I type

```
cd ~
pwd
```

I got `Users/KesongXie`
 and i tired to `ls` and expect to see my .ssh, but it's still invisible. then i tried to

```
cd .ssh
```

I found out i then entered the .ssh directory, use `ls` , i can see the following result:

```
github_rsa  github_rsa.pub  id_dsa      id_dsa.pub  known_hosts
```

the keys do store in the .ssh folder , but i wonder why i can not load the private key using

```
ssh-add /Users/KesongXie/.ssh/id_dsa
```

Comment: Try to copy-and-paste the command you entered in your post into the terminal. It should work. You must have mistyped it into your terminal the first time.

Answer (score 1):

`-bash: ssh-add/Users/KesongXie/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory` is a strange error message - It means Bash thought you tried to run the literal command `ssh-add/Users/KesongXie/.ssh/id_dsa`. Are you sure you used an ASCII space (0x20) after `ssh-add`?